# ¿Que es lo que esta mal en mi codigo?

Tags: javascript

Tengo que hacer una función que elimine las letras a, b y c de un string y devuelva la versión modificada sin esas letras. Pense que habia encontrado una solución pero no es así ya que me devuelve el mismo string que es pasado por parámetro a la función, la verdad no se que esta mal. Si alguien me dice me error le voy a agradecer mucho

```js
function deleteAbc(cadena) {
  let nuevaCadena = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
    if (cadena[i] !== "a" || cadena[i] !== "b" || cadena[i] !== "c") {
      nuevaCadena = nuevaCadena + cadena[i]
    }
  }
  return nuevaCadena
}
console.log(deleteAbc('abecedario'));
```

Comment: Tu if está mal. Debes cambiar !== por === y negar ! toda la expresión, o cambiar el || por &&

Answer (score 2):

El error es de lógica.

Pongamos de caso de que `cadena[i] = "a"`, entonces si analizamos las condiciones del `if` tenemos que:

- `cadena[i] !== "a"` es `false`
- `cadena[i] !== "b"` es `true`
- `cadena[i] !== "c"` es `true`

Como estas utilizando el operador "or" (`||`) entonces:

```
false || true || true => true
```

#### Solución:

Tenés que usar "and" (`&&`)

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function deleteAbc(cadena) {
  let nuevaCadena = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
    if (cadena[i] !== "a" && cadena[i] !== "b" && cadena[i] !== "c") {
      nuevaCadena = nuevaCadena + cadena[i]
    }
  }
  return nuevaCadena
}
console.log(deleteAbc('abecedario'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que cambiar el operador **`||`** por **`&&`**:

```js
function deleteAbc(cadena) {
  let nuevaCadena = ""
  for (let i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
    if (cadena[i] !== "a" && cadena[i] !== "b" && cadena[i] !== "c") {
      nuevaCadena = nuevaCadena + cadena[i]
    }
  }
  return nuevaCadena;
}

console.log(deleteAbc('abecedario'));
```

O también podrías usar este ejemplo, en donde se usa el operador **`||`**:

```js
function deleteAbc(cadena) {
  var nuevaCadena = cadena.split('');
  for (var x = 0; x < cadena.length; x++) {
    var char = cadena[x].toLowerCase();
    if (char === "a" || char === "b" || char === "c") {
      nuevaCadena[x] = '';
    }
  }
  return nuevaCadena.join('');
}

console.log(deleteAbc('abecedario'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay una función que se llama REPLACE donde le indicas que caracter vas a sustituir y por cuál, que en tu caso, es en blanco.

Aquí te coloqué un ejemplo sencillo donde no hay “FOR”, ya que el número de letras que vas a eliminar son fijas, si fueran dinámicas colocaría dos variables que recibirías en la función, primero un arreglo de las letras que quieres quitar y la otra la cadena.

```
<script>
        function deleteAbc(dato){
          var cadena = dato;
          var nuevaCadena ="";
          nuevaCadena = cadena.replace("a", "");
          nuevaCadena = nuevaCadena.replace("b", "");
          nuevaCadena = nuevaCadena.replace("c", "");
            return nuevaCadena
          }


          console.log(deleteAbc("abecedario"))
    </script>
```

ACLARATORIA: Este código solo va a remplazar el carácter específico respetando si está en minúscula o mayúscula.